# hash (#) vs end charCode from keypress event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

In Firefox (8) both the <kbd>end</kbd> key and <kbd>#</kbd> key have the same charCode (35). Is there a way to tell them apart?

I made a quick demo on jsfiddle. Just type in the input box and it will show you the charCode/key that you pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/PfAeW/

I'm building a rich text editor where <kbd>#</kbd> triggers an autocomplete function. I need to cater to international users (UK keyboards) so looking to see if <kbd>shift</kbd> is being pressed would not work.

Comment: fyi, period (`.`) also translates to `delete` (in case that matters as well) **EDIT** apostrophe (`'`) = `right`, left parenthesis (`(`) = `down` (among others) (Something tells me it's mootools not catching the key correctly and mis-reporting [though that is only speculative])

Comment: You're right, it's Mootools. Using String.fromCharCode(event.event.charCode) in Mootools provides the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use the [Keyboard Manager](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Keyboard) to bind to "shift+3"?

Comment: shift+3 is not # on UK keyboards. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of codes for key events in the DOM: `charCode`, which represents the character for printable keys and `keyCode` which represents the physical key pressed on the keyboard.

It happens that the charCode of '#' is 35 and the keyCode of the end key is also 35, but they come with totally different number-to-meaning mappings.

Mootools exposes a `.code` on events which conflates the two codes, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just so there's an answer...

It looks like Mootools is mis-representing the keypress (which on your test also show mis-mappings of the following as well:

```
Key Pressed        How Moo Sees It
-----------        ---------------
end                #          35
.   (period)       delete     46
(   (left paren.)  down       40
'   (apos.)        right      39
```

But, you may be able to use the [Keyboard](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Keyboard) (coupled with the [Keys list](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Event.Pseudos.Keys)) and bind to the correct sequence. I'm not fluent in moo-tools, but given the document examples I don't see why the following wouldn't work:

```
var kb = new Keyboard({
    defaultEventType: 'keypress'
});
kb.addEvents({
    'end': fnEnd,
});
```

*Disclaimer: More-or-less showing alternative (or so is my understanding based on docs) than solution. I **do not** know if the above code works, but it should. I am, however, not sure how you'd bind the above to a specific control, so that may be one limitation that Keyboard has over a direct binding.*

Comment: my solution was to use String.fromCharCode(event.charCode || event.which) to get the key instead of using the Mootools shortcut.

Comment: @gpbmike: Then feel free to answer your own question and post it as an answer. I'm sure others would benefit from it, and I'll give it an up-vote. Once enough time passes, you'll be able to accept it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can checking for `shift` (`event.code == 16`) key in keydown event and preserve value of them and when keypress will be triggered you are sure if `code` from `keydown` event was 16 and now is 35  `#` really is pressed. Uless there is another way to check the shift is pressed:)